# ThinkPad Edge 14 hangs during shutdown - what could cause this?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, shutdown, thinkpad

When I try to shut down, it goes to the "Shutting down" page and just simply stays there forever until I force a shut down holding the power button. Then at restart I have to choose to start normal (of course I could choose a different mode but it does fine with normal).

The machine is brand new, and I loaded my software so I am assuming something is running in the background causing this but I can't figure it out.

Operating system is Windows 7 Home Premium.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First step should be to boot and immediately shut down: if it still has the problem then you know the program is getting loaded at start. go to msconfig and set it to selective startup, then next part is going to be tedious. disable all start up programs and see if it still gives you this issue. If not enable them one by one until you find the culprit. If it is STILL giving you issues you will have to begin disabling services and shutting down be very careful with this and make sure you research any service before disabling it.